# How to install Wine (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: software-installation, wine

No matter which way I try to install Wine It doesn't install, I'm new to Ubuntu, but its not hard to copy and paste and click "install". I tried to install it via Commands on the Wine website, and commands on a Youtube tutorial, then I tried the one in the software store (I didn't use that one in the beginning because I wanted the stable release not the development release.) Does anyone know why its doing this, and how to fix it?

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key
sudo apt-key add Release.key
sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

Those are the exact commands that were in the Youtube Tutorial and the Wine HQ website.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the exact commands you tried and the output from them.

Comment: try playonlinux from the software manager

Comment: We need the output so we can see what errors you got.

Answer (score 0):

You don't give details of the errors you are encountering, so this is a guess.

This simple set of terminal commands should work. If it doesn't, please edit your question and include the errors you received.

Open a terminal and type:

`sudo apt install wine-stable`

Enter your password when prompted (you will not get any feedback from entering your password, not even ****).

Comment: I added the terminal commands as you asked